# pytest: Is it possible to use pytest-datadir fixtures in Class setup/teardown

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I had a class where I was making use of the setup_method:

```
class TestClassUnderTest():
    def setup_method(self, method):
        with open(foo, "r") as bar_fd:
            yaml_output = yaml.load(bar_fd, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
        self.object_under_test = ClassUnderTest(yaml_output)

    def test_initialization(self, mocker):
        assert not self.object_under_test.boolean_attribute
```

I want to use pytest-datadir plugin to manage my data files in the setup_method:

```
class TestClassUnderTest():
    def setup_method(self, method, shared_datadir): # shared_datadir is the fixture from the plug-in
        with open(str(shared_datadir.joinpath("name_of_file_inside_the_dir")), "r") as bar_fd:
            yaml_output = yaml.load(bar_fd, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
        self.object_under_test = ClassUnderTest(yaml_output)
```

The error message 
`ERROR tests/test_common.py::TestClassUnderTest::test_initialization - TypeError: setup_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shared_datadir'`
leads me to believe that the arrangement of the arguments is strict and do not work the way I expect them to.

Can I pass in a random fixture into a setup/teardown method ?

Comment: I'd love to know a good answer for this, but in the meantime, i just used `my_datadir = Path(__file__).parent / 'data'`

Comment: Got anyway? I require something similar as well.

Comment: Not yet, maybe I will do a bit of investigation.